# DocuSign: How to disable the "Style Selection" in adopt siganture

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I do not want to allow the signer to use the preformatted signature. Rather they should draw and upload the signature.

I know there is an option to disable this in "Adopt Signature Setting". But How can I achieve this with NodeJs SDK?

Answer (score 0):

The account (not an individual envelope) can be set to require the signers to draw a signature each time, or upload a file with their signature, etc. There are a number of settings available.

The [admin guide](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&bundleId=pik1583277475390&topicId=dsz1583277358168.html&_LANG=enus) discusses some settings, and I think there are other settings that DocuSign customer service can set for you. Your account admin can discuss with DocuSign customer service.